# Calculating value of pi using recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

so I'm trying to calculate value of pi using recursion. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

double pi (int n){
    double s = 0;
    s = s + 4 * ( pow(-1,n+1 ) * (1/(2*n-1) ) );
    if( n > 0 ) {
        pi( n - 1 );
    }
    return s;
}

int main(void) {

    int n,i;
    float *A;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    A = (float*)malloc( n *sizeof(float) );
    for( i = 0 ; i < n; i++ ) {
        A[i] = pi( i + 1 );
    }
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        printf( "%f\n", A[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

for value of `n = 1`, it returns the expected answer, `pi = 4`, but for any other value it computes that `pi = 0`. Anyone care to explain why?

Comment: you aren't saving the value returned by your recursive call.  Change `pi(n-1);` to `s += pi(n-1);` for a start.

Comment: Tip: use human-readable variable names. Short, cryptic names like `s`, `n` and `A` only serve to hinder code maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

use                `s = s + 4 * ( pow(-1,n+1 ) * (1.0/(2*n-1) ) );`
 instead of   `s = s + 4 * ( pow(-1,n+1 ) * (1/(2*n-1) ) );`
because **if n=2** , the **(1/(2*n-1))** part will give **1/3** , and as **both 1 and 3 are integers**, result will be converted to **integer** that is **0**, thats why u get a 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>


double pi (int n){
    double s = 0;
    if( n > 0 ) {
      s = s + 4 * ( pow(-1,n+1 ) * (1/(2*(double)n-1) ) );
      s +=  pi( n - 1 );
    }
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    int n,i;
    float *A;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    A = (float*)malloc( n *sizeof(float) );
    for( i = 0 ; i < n; i++ ) {
        A[i] = pi( i + 1 );
    }
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        printf( "%f\n", A[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

These are the things that you are doing wrong:

> In the function **pi**, you are only returning the value of **s** from the first recursive call. The value of **s** from successive recursive calls is lost.

..

> In this piece of code **1/(2*n-1)** , since n is an integer, integer division takes place. You need to cast n to a double to avoid losing digits after the floating point

..

> The piece of code, `s = s + 4 * ( pow(-1,n+1 ) * (1/(2*n-1) ) );` should be placed inside the if condition `if( n > 0 )`
>   This is because, when n equals 0, you will simply be adding another 4 to the value of **s**.

```
s = s +  4 * ( pow(-1, 0+1 ) * (1/(2*0-1) ) );
s = s +  4 * ( -1 * -1)
s = s +  4
```

Comment: You should explain the reason, not just write the code.